# ReIndex Number List but keep Duplicates in Order C#

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to reorder a list that essentially gets rid of duplicates. Which I have been able to do. The part that is tripping me up is, if there are duplicates I want to keep them, and maintain the order

Examples -

Input = 1,3,3,4
Output = 1,2,2,3

Input = 1,3,5,6,6
Output = 1,2,3,4,4

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT -

Code I've attempted.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numList.Count; i++)
{
    if (numList[i - 1] == numList[i])
    {
        foreach (var item in numList.Where(x => x == numList[i - 1]))
        {
            testList.Add(item);
            i++;
        }
        foreach (var item in testList)
        {
            numList.Add(item);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        numList[i - 1] = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: The output set doesn't exist in the input set... That doesn't sound like "reordering".

Comment: seems like the output set in the index +1 of the objects in the input set

Comment: So if you are trying show us some code you tried to write.

Comment: How can `1,3,3,4` become `1,2,2,3` .... magic ???

Comment: presumably what you actually mean here is that you want to get rid of the **gaps**, but keep the number of contiguous elements? so... not actually re-ordered, but re-indexed?

Comment: I've modified the post to reflect some of the issues you've all raised.

Comment: @MarcGravell good catch ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has nothing to with sorting... but I think I understood what you are looking for, and the following code should provide it:

```
List<Int32> numbers = new List<Int32> { 1, 3, 3, 4 };
List<Int32> result = new List<Int32>(numbers.Count);

Int32 currentValue = 1;
Int32 lastNumber = numbers[0];

for (Int32 i = 0; i < numbers.Count; ++i)
{
    Int32 number = numbers[i];

    if (numbers[i] != lastNumber)
        ++currentValue;

    result.Add(currentValue);
    lastNumber = number;
}

foreach (Int32 number in result) 
    Console.WriteLine(number); // Output: 1, 2, 2, 3
```

Please, visit [this link](http://rextester.com/YLZUIA17488) to try a working demo, which implements the following function:

```
private static List<Int32> IndexNumbers(List<Int32> input)
{
    List<Int32> numbers = input.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
    List<Int32> result = new List<Int32>(input.Count);

    Int32 currentValue = 1;
    Int32 lastNumber = numbers[0];

    for (Int32 i = 0; i < numbers.Count; ++i)
    {
        Int32 number = numbers[i];

        if (numbers[i] != lastNumber)
            ++currentValue;

        result.Add(currentValue);
        lastNumber = number;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This looks really good. Thank you for a thorough answer. I need to read into it for a little while to really get it. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Note that it is unclear whether we expect the input to be out of order or not. If we're allowed to change the input array, a simple `Array.Sort(values)` at the top of `Rebase` would ensure that aspect.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", Rebase(1, 3, 3, 4))); // 1, 2, 2, 3
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", Rebase(1, 3, 5, 6, 6))); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 4
}
static int[] Rebase(params int[] values)
{
    // Array.Sort(values); // if not already sorted, and allowed to mutate
    int prev = values[0];
    var result = new int[values.Length];
    int val = result[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        var current = values[i];
        if (current != prev)
        {
            val++;
            prev = current;
        }
        result[i] = val;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that you *could* also choose to *overwrite* the input array rather than create a new array to return.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This looks similar to some of other answers, I'll study it and try to learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using LINQ:

```
var reindexed = numList
    .OrderBy(n => n)
    .GroupBy(n => n)
    .SelectMany((g, i) => g
        .Select(e => i + 1));
```

Comment: it as a certain elegance in terms of display - so +1 for sure, but ... it may be *much* less efficient than the direct options

Comment: Thanks for this. Nice to see a simple version, but I like the longer forms right now. Easier to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

First off, figure out what the old number should match to. `Distinct` and `OrderBy` are probably you're friends here

```
List<int> input = new List<int> { 1, 3, 3, 4 };

var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
var index = 1;
foreach (var n in input.Distinct().OrderBy(n => n)) {
    dictionary.Add(n, index++);
}

var output = input.Select(n => dictionary[n]);
```